# Approve modified posts

Tags: posts

I would to be able to re-approve my contributor's edits to an already published post. I.e, when they edit a post - it gets sent back for approval.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This exact functionality is not available in wordpress core. You may want to completely block them from modifying the published posts. See this capability-
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_published_posts

Otherwise you'll need a plugin

Comment: is there a plugin for this?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this seems to be a good solution-
[http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revisionary/screenshots/](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revisionary/screenshots/)